# Connecting to systemd service's standard output/error

Tags: systemd, journald

I have a simple systemd service that runs for some time and then exits. It usually gets triggered by a systemd timer but sometimes I want to run it manually (well, from a script). The problem is - I need that script to output to terminal whatever my service outputs and do couple other things when the service exits.

I'd really like to be able to do `systemctl start foo.service` instead of moving my `ExecStart=` to a bash script and just running it for a couple of reasons:

1. I want the behavior to be exactly the same. My experience tells me that things running from shell and from shell-from-systemd sometimes behave differently.
2. I don't know how to limit resources used by script like with systemd unit's `Limit*=` directives.
3. I need there to be only one instance of the service at most, which starting via systemctl ensures, but starting via script doesn't (unless I complicate it with pidfile handling).

Basically, what I want is:

`tail --pid $MY_PID -f my.log`

but done with journalctl.

Using:

`journalctl -u my.service -o cat --no-pager -f`

after starting the service works almost like I want it to, but it doesn't exit after my service exits.

If possible, I'd like not to use `StandardOutput=` and `StandardError=` to redirect my logs to a file and running `tail` command from above on it, because I'd like journalctl to store and manage my logs.

I know about `StandardOutput=tty` option and judging from documentation it should do what I want, but I'm not sure how it'll work when the service is being ran by the timer.

What options do I have?